# How to build a cupertino textfield

Tags: flutter, layout, textfield

How can I achieve something like this in Flutter?
I am talking about the 2 textfield on grey. Are they a Cupertino Textfield?

[image: textfield]

Comment: You want only `CupertinoTextField` ?

Comment: that could be nice, so i can match IOS style. What you got in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

#### Using [**`CupertinoTextField`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoTextField-class.html)

```
 Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        height: 100,
        width: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CupertinoTextField(
              placeholder: 'Required',
              prefix: Text(
                'Name',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(),
            ),
            Divider(
              thickness: 1,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            CupertinoTextField(
              prefix: Text(
                'Card Number',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

#### Using [**`TextField`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html)

```
  Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        height: 135,
        width: 300,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: Colors.grey.shade300,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 15,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Name',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: "Required",
              ),
            ),
            Divider(
              thickness: 1,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 15,
                    right: 10,
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Card Number',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use cupertinotextfield.borderless to meet your requirements. Here is an example:

```
Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[400],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: const [
                CupertinoTextField.borderless(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 65, top: 10, right: 6, bottom: 10),
                  prefix: Text('Name'),
                  placeholder: 'Required',
                ),
                Divider(
                  thickness: 1,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                CupertinoTextField.borderless(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, top: 10, right: 6, bottom: 10),
                  prefix: Text('Card Number'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Play around with the widgets parameters to customise it to your own needs.

[image]